# Why is input element retaining the value? Data binding is not applying the second time

Tags: polymer, lit

Using lit element... I have this element called single transaction. From the list of transactions page, I click on single transaction and go to a new page with single transaction.

In the notes input element:

1. I edit the input and change 'foo' to 'bar'
2. I do not save
3. I go back to main page.
4. I then go back to the same single transaction.

The notes input has the edited value `bar`. It should have `foo` since I did not save the value. Why did the `bar` value persist? It seems when I go back single-transaction element the `.singleTransData=${this.singleTransData}` data binding would show the original value `foo`. It's like the data binding logic is not running again and updating the element.

Before input is modified with bar:
[image]

When input value persists without saving:
[image]

parent element

```js
      <single-transaction
        data-el="add-catergory"
        .singleTransData=${this.singleTransData}
        id="single-transaction"></single-transaction>
```

single-transaction element:

```js
  static properties = {                                                
    singleTransData: {                                                 
      type: Object,                                                    
    },                                                                 
    label: {                                                           
      type: String,                                                    
    },                                                                 
  };                                                                   
                                                                                                                                            
  constructor() {                                                      
    super();                                                           
    this.singleTransData = {};                                         
  }                                                                    
                                                                       
  render() {                                                           
                                                                       
    return html`                                                       
          <mwc-icon-button                                             
            @click=${this.#leavePage}                                  
            icon="arrow_back"></mwc-icon-button>                       
                                                                       
          <span class="row">                                           
            <md-outlined-text-field                                    
              label="notes"                                            
              data-key="notes"                                         
              value="${this.singleTransData.notes}"                    
              ></md-outlined-text-field>                               
          </span>                                                      
    `                                                                  
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're keeping the DOM that contains the `<single-transaction>` connected while you go to the main page, say either by showing the current page with just CSS, or using the `cache()` directive, then the input, it's current value, and the binding to it are all preserved.

Lit bindings remember their previous value and only update the DOM when the data changes. This means that for elements that change their internal state, Lit won't reset it when you re-render with Lit using the same value as the previously rendered value.

That is, if you render with Lit and value `"foo"`, internally change the value to `"bar"`, then re-render with Lit and value `"foo"`, Lit won't set the property because for all it knows the value is still `"foo"` and doesn't need to be changed.

This only happens with elements that modify their own internal state (sometimes called "uncontrolled components" in React-land). To help with this Lit has the `live()` directive: https://lit.dev/docs/templates/directives/#live

`live()` bypasses Lit's internal binding value storage and always checks against the live value of the property you're bound to.

`<md-outlined-text-field>` already uses `live()` to bind to it's internal `<input>`, and updates it's `value` property on the `input` event, so it's `value` property is always up-to-date. You should be able to add `live()` to your template to achieve the same:

```html
            <md-outlined-text-field                                    
              label="notes"                                            
              data-key="notes"                                         
              value="${live(this.singleTransData.notes)}"
              ></md-outlined-text-field>
```

Comment: Something to add here, it should be binding to the value property with a `.value`. otherwise it's an attribute binding.